# SPServices - GetListItems - formatting results

Tags: list, list-view, caml-query, spservices, camlviewfields

I am using SPServices in Sharepoint 2013 to get some results from cutom list named "navigator" presented here:

[image]

and for this purpose I am using code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.SPServices-2014.01.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: true,
        listName: "navigator",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='URL' /><FieldRef Name='DisplayOrder' /><FieldRef Name='Target' /><FieldRef Name='Category' /></ViewFields>",
        CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='DisplayOrder' Ascending='true' /></OrderBy></Query>",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                var title = ($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
                var href = ($(this).attr("ows_URL")).split(",")[0];
                var target = ($(this).attr("ows_Target"));
                var liHtml = "<li><a href='"+ href +"' target='"+ target +"'>" + title + "</a></li>";
                $("#navigator").append(liHtml);
            });
        }
    });
});
            </script>
            <ul id="navigator" />
```

I get list of all items like this:

[image]

But I would like to achieve something like this:

[image]

Is it possible to use "Category" as parent for this elements?

Comment: is only 1 category having 1 list item?

Comment: This is only example of an idea. Each category will have more items 10 at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So upon your feedback try this one on. The divs will float and it will add a new div based on the category. You need to order items first by category. Then Display order.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: true,
    listName: "navigator",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='URL' /><FieldRef Name='DisplayOrder' /><FieldRef Name='Target' /><FieldRef Name='Category' /></ViewFields>",
    CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Category" Ascending='true'/><FieldRef Name='DisplayOrder' Ascending='true' /></OrderBy></Query>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
```

//Added previous category here
var previouscategory="";

```
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
            var title = ($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
    // Set current category
    var category = ($(this).attr("Category"));
            var href = ($(this).attr("ows_URL")).split(",")[0];
            var target = ($(this).attr("ows_Target"));

    if(category !=previouscategory)
    {
        $("#navigator").append("<div style='float:left'><h4>"+category+"</h4>");
    }

            var liHtml = "<li><a href='"+ href +"' target='"+ target +"'>" + title + "</a></li>";
            $("#navigator").append(liHtml);

    if(category !=previouscategory)
    {
        $("#navigator").append("</div>);
    }

    previouscategory= category;
        });
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to use your code and now I don't see any results - blank screen. Should I add div with id="navigator" or any other element?

Comment: Yes please try with that. I could not try this on mine as I did not have your environment. Logically this code should work. If not, try removing the float.

Comment: I managed to show some results like this:
[link](http://pwojtkow.vot.pl/sharepoint/list_view4.png)
by using this code:

`if(category != previouscategory)
{
$("#navigator").append("<div style='float:left;'><h1>"+category+"</h1><br> "+liHtml+"");                    
}`
Now I need to remove duplicate names of categories somehow

Comment: Thats great. Now you can add more style and make it work better. Also replace h1 tags with lower ones like h3,h4 or some other tags.

Comment: To remove the duplicates, make sure the category != previous category comes true only when a new category is coming

Comment: Could you help me with that duplicate problem? How to check if new Category is there?

Comment: yes. Please try validating the category !- previouscategory. This is where the new category should be created. Basically if the same category is there, the code inside should not execute. Can you just verify that? If so, this will work perfectly.